# How do I create a lambda function to print numbers containing x and y in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

I want to create a list which contains numbers with only 9 and 8 in ascending order, between 0 to 1000. How do I do that via a `lambda` function in Python?

The expected output would be:

```
[8, 9, 88, 89, 98, 99, 888, 889, 898, 899, 988, ...]
```

Comment: why do you want to do it with a lambda?

Comment: then say that. lambda != performance.

Comment: you could use a list comprehension which may (or may not be) faster.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not use a lambda here at all, but would use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead to produce the digits:

```
from itertools import product    
[int(''.join(d)) for l in range(1, 4) for d in product('89', repeat=l)]
```

This does the absolute minimum work required for the output desired, short of hardcoding the list.

The expanded version would be:

```
results = []
# ranging from 1 to 3 digits
for l in range(1, 4):
    # all combinations of l digits out of 8 and 9
    for digits in product('89', repeat=l):
        # put the digits together into one string, convert to an integer
        value = int(''.join(digits))
        results.append(value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [int(''.join(d)) for l in range(1, 4) for d in product('89', repeat=l)]
[8, 9, 88, 89, 98, 99, 888, 889, 898, 899, 988, 989, 998, 999]
```

You can wrap *the list comprehension* in a function to specify the digits to be used and the maximum number of digits to produce:

```
def generate_numbers(digits, length):
    return [int(''.join(d)) for l in range(length) for d in product(digits, repeat=l + 1)]

generate_numbers('89', 3)
generate_numbers('123', 5)
```

Comment: Wow! 

Do you mind adding an explanation? That will be helpful for the learners like me.

Comment: @RakeshS: added a non-list-comp version with comments for you. Do read the `itertools.product()` documentation and experiment with the output that tool produces to see why this works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, deleted my answer in favour of this one. using `product` from itertools is clearly the best solution here.

Answer (score -1):

You want list so you can use

```
print [x  for x in arr if ('8' in str(x) or '9' in str(x))]
```

where arr is your list

Comment: This is very inefficient, assuming `arr` is simply `range(1000)` It is also incorrect because it will capture `18` for example, which is not valid.

Comment: My bad. Missunderstud the question.